# Response from Server using Jquery and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

im having a problem with getting any response from my server using Jquery and Ajax.

Server side:

```
$data = strtotime("now");
echo $data; // $data
```

Client side:

```
html code...
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../modjpicker2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

modjpicker2.js:

```
$(function() {
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajaxtime",
        data: "{}",
        success: function(response) {
            var currentTime = new Date();
        }
    });
});
```

And var currentTime is just not being created... Some how request doesn't go through...
Forgot to note that jQuery is working fine all scripts are attached in header and php is working good as well, link ajaxtime is live also.

Comment: If it doesn't get executed it means there was an error with your request, add the error method to your ajax to see what it is.

Comment: url:ajaxtime should be something like url:"http://yourdomain/ajaxtime.php",

Comment: Filename should be ajaxtime.php not ajaxtime. If you want to store the response in var currentTime, you have to give as var currentTime=response;

Comment: Sheikh Heera, nithi: ajaxtime is user friendly url, you can call it ajaxtime.php it doesn't change anything, and using the whole path doesn't change anything aswell.

Comment: slash197: would you please give a simplest example on how to use error method in my case? I'm not a pro with ajax yet.

Answer (score 1):

In your html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../modjpicker2.js"></script>
```

It should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../modjpicker2.js"></script>
```

Comment: "..." means there is a long address, there is no ... in address, modjpicker2.js works fine, the code provided is only part of the whole script, the second part works good.

Answer (score 0):

I had kind of the same problem: My servers responses won't get handled by jQuery or JavaScript. It seems that nothing were transmitted.

I solved the issue by enabling HTTP access control on my server( More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Here's my solution:

[jQuery client won't accept my server responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198637/jquery-client-wont-accept-my-server-responses)

Hope I can help! Let me know if it worked